# SQL Search using another Field as String Value

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have an idea for a SQL query but I'm not sure if this is even possible.  Let's imagine I have a table with 3 columns:

```
IDNUMBER, PARAGRAPH, ANIMAL
```

- `IDNUMBER` is just a key identifier number.
- `PARAGRAPH` is always going to have a big block of text, and sometimes it will mention an animal in the paragraph.
- `ANIMAL` will always have a set small value like "Dog" or "Monkey".

Is there a way, for each `IDNUMBER`, to take the value in the Animal column and 
use that value for a string search of the corresponding `Paragraph` column?  I'm not sure if I would need to assign the Animal value to some sort of string variable for each loop?  This is much more of conceptual question at this point because I'm not sure if this is even possible in SQL, but something like:

```
SELECT
    idnumber, paragraph, animal
FROM 
    zootable
WHERE 
    paragraph NOT LIKE ('%currentAnimalValue%')
```

Sorry this one is so hand-wavy, I'm just looking for a sanity check on this one. Thanks for any help/wisdom you can provide!   :)

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Does each paragraph relate to the animal in the table?

Comment: I work mostly in Teradata and Oracle SQL Developer, so either of those would be good.

Comment: '%' || animal || '%'

Comment: Keith, each animal value would be directly related to that particular IDNumber and Paragraph. So the Animal value might be "Panda", the paragraph would be about Pandas, but it might not mention "Panda" by name, if that helps.  I would like to identify when the paragraph does / does not specifically mention its corresponding animal value.

Comment: I agree with the below answer. I just wanted to add that you need to be careful with wildcards. For instance if you had a paragraph that had the word `pants` in it and the animal was `ants`.

Comment: I suggest you change the schema, one table for animals, one for paragraphs

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.paragraph not like '%' || t.animal || '%' ;
```

Some databases use `concat()`, `+`, or `&` for string concatenation.

Comment: I am amazed at how quickly you guys cracked that!  Thank you so much this is getting added to the Favorites library!!   :)

Answer (score 2):

Gordon's answer may produce some incorrect matches.

Eg: `'panda' like '%pandas%'` returns True. 
     `'ant' like '%pant%'` returns True

To avoid this you should use `regexp` (in Oracle) to consider word boundaries (assuming paragraph column is space-separated).

For matches use:

```
select * from t 
where regexp_like(paragraph,'(^|\s)'||animal||'(\s|$)')
```

For non-matches use

```
select * from t 
where not regexp_like(paragraph,'(^|\s)'||animal||'(\s|$)')
```